# Create custom role for Lucee+MongoDB application

Tags: mongodb, coldfusion, lucee

First, I'm really new to MongoDB. So apologies if this should be obvious...

I have a collection named "jobs" with my FOO database. I'm trying to set proper rights, but wish to setup proper rights on the collection level, and not just the database.

I've read that you can do so my creating a custom role. Now, I've done, by providing only the actions "find", "update", "insert", "remove" (which are self-explanatory... my app needs to be able to select, insert, update and delete documents).

Now, my app is also a coldfusion app, running through Lucee. I've installed the latest MongoDB Lucee extension (3.4.2.59).

Now, my question is that when establising a connection within my CFML script, a simple dump() of my mongo db object will give me an error about not have enough privileges to run the command listCollections:

> Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on FOO to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "FOO" }' on server 127.0.0.1:27017.
>
> The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on FOO to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "FOO" }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }

The only way I could get it to work, was by also adding the listCollections possible actions on the DB level only of my custom role. This is my role's defnition now :

```js
db.createRole(
    {
      role: "jobsAdmin",
      privileges: [
         { resource: { db: "FOO", collection: "jobs" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
         { resource: { db: "FOO", collection: "" }, actions: [ "listCollections" ] }
      ],
      roles: []
    }
);
```

I'm just wondering if I did this right? In Mongo's documentation it is said that one without permission for listCollections can still retrieve the collection info by setting the authorizedCollections and nameOnly options to true:

[image]
[image]

SO, I'm wondering:

1. did I setup this right ?
2. why does the Lucee extension not use these options of authorizedCollections and nameOnly if it really needs to perform a listCollections regardless (it seems to do so when I do a simple dump(), or a remove(), or an insert(), and possible other actions...)? Could this be a bug of the extension?

```js
// create connection
var db = MongoDBConnect("FOO","mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/");
dump(db);

// clear out all documents
db["jobs"].remove({});

// insert some data
db["jobs"].insert({
  "name": "John Doe"
});
```

Much thanks for your time and input.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Did you cross-check accessing the same database with a different tool, to rule out a possible database misconfiguration?

Comment: I had tried an insert directly within mongosh, and without the listCollections: it did work with mongosh. Just not with the Lucee / Java driver... Perhaps bad version of the Java driver ?

Comment: Maybe. It's open source, so you should be able to analyze the stack trace and look up the code on Github in order to find out what exactly it does when the error occurs. That would be my next step.